# Как исправить Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пытаюсь писать jQuery скрипты на этом [сайте](http://brandivo.com/managed-website/), но они не работают, потому что Консоль показывает ошибку **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input** и указывает на первую строчку в html файле **<!DOCTYPE html>**. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем проблема и исправить ошибку! Заранее спасибо.

Comment: где-то незакрытая скобка

Answer (score 1):

Хм...
А ничего что jQuery там вообще нет, как, впрочем, и других скриптов?
Сниппет:
`javascript:(function(){if(window.jQuery)m='You are running jQuery version: '+jQuery.fn.jquery; else m='jQuery is not installed';alert(m);})();`
Определять по магическому шару нет возможности - забыл его в других штанах.

Да и чуть подробнее надо бы описать проблему - что вбивал, что выдавало кроме сабжа, etc.

Comment: @TheDoctor Как это нет jQery - в хедере есть такая строчка: **wp_enqueue_script("jquery");** ?!

Comment: @TheDoctor Вот, что я получил: *You are running jQuery version 1.8.3*

Comment: @eprivalov1, я не знаком с WP, но наличие вызова этой функции не гарантирует вставку, видимо.  
Я смотрю на сорцы страницы и не вижу ни одного JS-кода или вставки файла с этим кодом.

Comment: @TheDoctor Но код JS, который Вы написали в ответе, показывает что jQuery подключен...

Comment: @eprivalov1, странно, у меня вообще ни одного скрипта, да и файл какой-то... кусочный - пробелы и табуляция кучами.

Photo 1 - http://s020.radikal.ru/i709/1503/18/704154835252.png  
Photo 2 - http://s017.radikal.ru/i432/1503/73/42c572d3ca7f.png  
Chrome

Comment: @eprivalov1, если `wp_enqueue_script("jquery");` присутствует, а эффекта нет, значит надо еще закинуть `wp_head()` в тот же несчастный хедер.

Comment: @Etki wp_head() присутствует!

Comment: @eprivalov1 до или после enqueue? не заключен ли он внутрь какого-нибудь if?